# Parsing XML with throws unknown key error in function but works at command prompt

Tags: python, xml

I'm running Python 2.7.12 in Anaconda 4.1.1. I installed untangle to parse a pretty complex XML document.

Here's my code:

```
import untangle

obj = untangle.parse('ear.xml')

for rd in obj.SaData.Session.Test.Data.RecordedData:
    tls = rd.Measured.TestLines
    tl = tls.Testline
    for line in tl:
        snl = line.SnLevel.cdata
        pn = line.PresentNoise.cdata
        print snl + " " + pn
```

This returns the following error message:

IndexError: Unknown key

But if I immediately run tl = tls.Testline from the command prompt, I don't get any error.

Gotta be something simple but I'm a noob so help appreciated.

EDIT: I can't attach a file and the fully expanded XML is too big to enter here. I will try to present a partially expanded version to give some sense of how the file is organized.

```
<SaData Version="2" xsi:schemaLocation="uuid:ee2fbfd9-47a5-4dc8-a9eb-42d9995802ab SaData.xsd">
<ClientInfo></ClientInfo>
<Session><Platform FirmwareVersion=""></Platform><Created>2016-09-21T11:08:58</Created>
<Changed>2016-09-21T11:08:58</Changed>
<Module Version="2.0.0.0">DPOAE</Module>
<ProtocolName>DP 2 - 10 kHz (8/octave)</ProtocolName>
<Settings></Settings>
<Test><TestName>DP-Gram</TestName>
<Settings></Settings>
<Data>
<RecordedData>
<Settings></Settings>
<Measured>
<Earside>Left</Earside>
<TestType>DPGram</TestType>
<Readonly>false</Readonly>
<PeakPressure>-5</PeakPressure>
<TestStatus>9</TestStatus>
<TestLines>
<TestLine></TestLine>
<TestLine></TestLine>
<TestLine></TestLine>
<TestLine></TestLine>
<TestLine></TestLine>
<TestLine></TestLine>
<TestLine></TestLine>
<TestLine></TestLine>
<TestLine></TestLine>
<TestLine></TestLine>
<TestLine></TestLine>
<TestLine></TestLine>
<TestLine></TestLine>
<TestLine></TestLine>
<TestLine></TestLine>
<TestLine></TestLine>
<TestLine></TestLine>
<TestLine></TestLine>
</TestLines>
<TimeStamp>2016-09-19T12:28:11.7110965-05:00</TimeStamp><Duration>PT1M30S</Duration>
</Measured>
<Calculated></Calculated>
<PrivateData></PrivateData>
</RecordedData><
RecordedData></RecordedData>
</Data>
</Test>
</Session></SaData>
```

Comment: We'd need to have a copy of the document to reproduce (and thus, to diagnose) this.

Comment: ...if you can't provide the full document, a subset you've tested to have just enough to reproduce the issue (that is, working from the command line, failing from the script) will do. Be sure to edit a copy of the (minimal) working command-line session into the question.

Comment: Do the script and the command-line session read the same `ear.xml` file?

Comment: What line of code generates the error?  From your explanation I assume it's `tl = tls.Testline`

Comment: @John Gordon, yes it is tl = tls.Testline that produces the error, and yes there is only one ear.xml file.

Comment: So both the script and the command line interpreter are run from the same working directory?

Comment: What do you mean by _immediately run `tl = tls.Testline` from the command prompt_?  You also run the lines before that, right?

Comment: Yes, I'm working in Spyder so I have a console beside the code editing window. I save and run the code and it prints the error to the command prompt. I start debugging at the console prompt by doing type(tls) >>>  <type 'instance'>. Then I run tl = tls.Testline and it completes without an error message. Then I enter type(tl) >>> <type 'list'>.

Answer (score 0):

It was a stupid typo. I wrote Testline when I should have written TestLine. Sorry to waste everyone's time.

Dessie